# XSLT For-Each Only Selecting First Element

Tags: xml, xslt

Looking for some thoughts - I have the following sample XML record:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bdems:bulkDataRecord xmlns:bdems="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/bdemsv1p0/imsbdemsFileData_v1p0">
  <bdems:transactionRecord>
    <bdems:transactionOpIdentifier>3064476-C-001355-01-2187-I0001</bdems:transactionOpIdentifier>
    <bdems:serviceName>cmsv1p0</bdems:serviceName>
    <bdems:interfaceName>sectionassociationmanager</bdems:interfaceName>
    <bdems:operationName>replaceSectionAssociation</bdems:operationName>
    <bdems:parameterSet>
      <bdems:parameterRecord>
        <bdems:parameterInvoc>In</bdems:parameterInvoc>
        <bdems:parameterName>sourcedId</bdems:parameterName>
        <bdems:parameterType>GUID</bdems:parameterType>
        <bdems:parameterValue>
          <bdems:guid>001355-01-2187-I0001</bdems:guid>
        </bdems:parameterValue>
      </bdems:parameterRecord>
      <bdems:parameterRecord>
        <bdems:parameterInvoc>In</bdems:parameterInvoc>
        <bdems:parameterName>sectionAssociationRecord</bdems:parameterName>
        <bdems:parameterType>SectionAssociationRecord</bdems:parameterType>
        <bdems:parameterValue>
          <cms:sectionAssociationRecord xmlns:cms="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/imscms_v1p0">
            <cms:sourcedGUID>
              <cms:refAgentInstanceID>CS</cms:refAgentInstanceID>
              <cms:sourcedId>001355-01-2187-I0001</cms:sourcedId>
            </cms:sourcedGUID>
            <cms:sectionAssociation>
              <cms:status>Active</cms:status>
              <cms:courseSectionIdList>
                <cms:courseSectionId>001355-01-2187-1-01-02642</cms:courseSectionId>
                <cms:courseSectionId>001355-01-2187-1-05-04486</cms:courseSectionId>
              </cms:courseSectionIdList>
              <cms:dataSource>CS</cms:dataSource>
              <cms:extension>
                <cms:extensionNameVocabulary>http://www.oracle.com/Enterprise/HCM/cmsv2p0/extensionnamevocabularyv1p0</cms:extensionNameVocabulary>
                <cms:extensionTypeVocabulary>http://www.imsglobal.org/lis/cmsv1p0/extensionvocabularyv1p0</cms:extensionTypeVocabulary>
                <cms:extensionField>
                  <cms:fieldName>Mode</cms:fieldName>
                  <cms:fieldType>String</cms:fieldType>
                  <cms:fieldValue>C</cms:fieldValue>
                </cms:extensionField>
              </cms:extension>
            </cms:sectionAssociation>
          </cms:sectionAssociationRecord>
        </bdems:parameterValue>
      </bdems:parameterRecord>
    </bdems:parameterSet>
  </bdems:transactionRecord>
</bdems:bulkDataRecord>
```

I am trying to parse it out into a more user friendly file with the following xsl.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:bdems="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/bdemsv1p0/imsbdemsFileData_v1p0" xmlns:cms="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/imscms_v1p0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <combinations>
      <xsl:for-each select="//bdems:transactionRecord">
        <combination>
          <xsl:attribute name="id"> <xsl:value-of select="bdems:transactionOpIdentifier" /> </xsl:attribute>
          <id><xsl:value-of select="bdems:transactionOpIdentifier" /></id>
          <xsl:for-each select="bdems:parameterSet/bdems:parameterRecord">
            <xsl:if test="bdems:parameterName = 'sectionAssociationRecord'">
              <courses>
                <xsl:for-each select="bdems:parameterValue/cms:sectionAssociationRecord/cms:sectionAssociation">
                  <xsl:if test="cms:status = 'Active'">
                    <xsl:for-each select="cms:courseSectionIdList">
                      <course><xsl:value-of select="cms:courseSectionId" /></course>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </courses>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </combination>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </combinations>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Everything works fine, except it's only pulling the first record from the cms:courseSectionId.

Any thoughts on why i'm only getting the first record?

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<combinations xmlns:bdems="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/bdemsv1p0/imsbdemsFileData_v1p0" xmlns:cms="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/imscms_v1p0">
  <combination id="3064476-C-001355-01-2187-I0001">
    <id>3064476-C-001355-01-2187-I0001</id>
    <courses>
      <course>001355-01-2187-1-01-02642</course>
    </courses>
  </combination>
</combinations>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last for each is on courseSectionList. There is only one list, with multiple courseSectionId's.  If you change the for-each select to the courseSectionId it will work.

I tested the change, resulting in the following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:bdems="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/bdemsv1p0/imsbdemsFileData_v1p0" xmlns:cms="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/imscms_v1p0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <combinations>
      <xsl:for-each select="//bdems:transactionRecord">
        <combination>
          <xsl:attribute name="id"> <xsl:value-of select="bdems:transactionOpIdentifier" /> </xsl:attribute>
          <id><xsl:value-of select="bdems:transactionOpIdentifier" /></id>
          <xsl:for-each select="bdems:parameterSet/bdems:parameterRecord">
            <xsl:if test="bdems:parameterName = 'sectionAssociationRecord'">
              <courses>
                <xsl:for-each select="bdems:parameterValue/cms:sectionAssociationRecord/cms:sectionAssociation">
                  <xsl:if test="cms:status = 'Active'">
                    <xsl:for-each select="cms:courseSectionIdList/cms:courseSectionId">
                      <course><xsl:value-of select="." /></course>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </courses>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </combination>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </combinations>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```